# Что такое "стоеросовый"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Есть такое ругательство — "дубина стоеросовая".
А что это такое — "стоеросовый"?

Comment: Вспомнился забавный случай с детской этимологией данного слова. Во 2 классе кто-то назвал меня, в записке, дубиной **сталерозовой**. Было даже приятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Однозначного мнения на счет происхождения слова "стоеросовый" нет, привожу версию грамоты.ру:

> Прилагательное стоеросовый, ввиду необычности словообразовательной модели, делает возможным предположение о семинарском происхождении оборота: оно возникло как переделка греческого *stauros* "кол, шест, свая" в сочетании однозначных слов дубина - *stauros*, которое превратилось в результате в выражение дубина стоеросовая.

Из других версий упомяну ещё народную: "стоеросовый" - от прямой, "стоя растущий". Якобы так называли корабельный лес. Но эта версия не подтверждается ни документально, ни фонетически (образование "стоеросовый" из "стоярастущий" невозможно).

Comment: ***фонетически (образование "стоеросовый" из "стоярастущий" невозможно)***
почему же невозможно?!
если от ставроса (стауроса) возможно, при том, что ставросом называют и крест и пересечение, то почему нельзя изготовить дубину из стоя растущего деревца, при том, что бывают криворастущие. фонетически переход звука я в звук е в данном случае вполне оправдан.

Comment: @ИскандерАлиев Почему? да хотя бы потому, что такой переход гласных (хотя и он сомнителен) вообще ничего не доказывает - при наличии нескольких пар согласных, переход которых друг в друга никакими фонетическими законами не фиксируется. Ну как Щ перейдет в В?

Answer (score 2):

Подробный анализ различных версий происхождения этого выражения приведен в [этой статье.](http://www.vestnik.vsu.ru/pdf/lingvo/2003/02/kretov.pdf)

Процитирую здесь коротко основные варианты, а также выводы работы.

> 17-томный “Словарь современного русского литературного языка” определяет это слово следующим образом : СТОЕРОСОВЫЙ «Растущий стоймя. О дереве. <> Грубо простореч. Употребляется в составе некоторых бранных выражений». При этом академический словарь в толковании слова полностью следует за В.И. Далем, впервые это слово зафиксировавшим.
>
> Имеется и другая этимология этого слова, предложенная Ж.Ж. Варбот, возводящей русское слово *стоерос* к греческому σταυρός ‘кол; позднее – крест’. Время словарной фиксации слова (середина 19-го века), его неодобрительная экспрессия и сниженная стилистическая окраска позволяют предположить лишь один канал проникновения древнегреческого слова в русское просторечие — это речь бурсаков и семинаристов.
>
> Таким образом, следует признать, что ближе к истине был читатель журнала “Русская речь” А.П. Правда из Воронежа, еще в 1968 году предложивший для словосочетания *дубина стоеросовая* (наряду с далевским) также объяснение ‘имеющая сто еросов (сучков) — вроде дубина неотесанная’.