# Историческое значение: "Дубина стоеросовая"

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика, сравнительный-оборот, фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать значение этого выражения и его **исторические корни**. Какой оттенок (эмоциональный, воле-изъявительный) носило это выражение раньше? И каков смысл фразы в наши дни?

Comment: Здесь смотрите https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/

Comment: Связка с греческим более чем весома.

Comment: @shampar - Спасибо огромное за коррекцию вопроса.